# How to create a PySpark Schema for a list of tuples?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, schema

What should be the correct *PySpark* Schema for the following list of tuples? I want to apply the schema on the following data:

```
[('a', 0.0), ('b', 6), ('c', 44), ('d', 107), ('e', 0), ('f', 3), ('g', 4), ('h', 0.025599999353289604), ('i', 0.03239999711513519), ('j', -0.03205680847167969), ('k', 0.10429033637046814), ('l', (34.190006256103516, 31.09000015258789, 31.099994659423828)), ('m', (-9.32000732421875, -9.32000732421875, -11.610000610351562)) ]
```

I want the result in the following format:
[Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8zXD.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tanjin answer should work although I would like to suggest another approach. Instead of finding out how many columns you should add to your schema to create a column of type array/list. The next code transforms your data into a rdd which instead of tuples contains rows of [key, value] where value is a list of double. Then you can easily apply the schema below.

```
def test():
    l = [('a', 0.0), 
    ('b', 6), 
    ('c', 44), 
    ('d', 107), 
    ('e', 0), 
    ('f', 3), 
    ('g', 4), 
    ('h', 0.025599999353289604), 
    ('i', 0.03239999711513519), 
    ('j', -0.03205680847167969), 
    ('k',0.10429033637046814), 
    ('l',(34.190006256103516, 31.09000015258789, 31.099994659423828)), 
    ('m',(-9.32000732421875, -9.32000732421875, -11.610000610351562))]

    # this schema should work for all your cases 
    schema = StructType([
        StructField("id", StringType(), False),
        StructField("num_list", ArrayType(DoubleType(), True), True)
    ])

    rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(l).map(lambda r: (r[0], to_float_list(r[1])))

    df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

    df.show(100, False)

def to_float_list(value):
    if type(value) is tuple:  
        return list(map(float, value))

    return [float(value)]
```

Notice that to_float_list function accepts either a tuple or a number and converts it to a list of double. This will output:

```
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|id |num_list                                                   |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|a  |[0.0]                                                      |
|b  |[6.0]                                                      |
|c  |[44.0]                                                     |
|d  |[107.0]                                                    |
|e  |[0.0]                                                      |
|f  |[3.0]                                                      |
|g  |[4.0]                                                      |
|h  |[0.025599999353289604]                                     |
|i  |[0.03239999711513519]                                      |
|j  |[-0.03205680847167969]                                     |
|k  |[0.10429033637046814]                                      |
|l  |[34.190006256103516, 31.09000015258789, 31.099994659423828]|
|m  |[-9.32000732421875, -9.32000732421875, -11.610000610351562]|
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandros Biratsis

Answer (score 2):

It would have been helpful to describe the tuple yourself before we make the Spark equivalent. In Python it seems like you have a tuple with 2 elements in it. The first is a `String`, and the second is another tuple made up of 3 `Double` values. The first few items don't necessarily comply to this, but you can't expect to have a 'dynamic' schema, but it seems like at the minimum the String and first number in the second tuple is always present. In any case one way to represent your type of this data is the following:
`(String, (Double, Double, Double))`

The corresponding Pyspark schema for this would be:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType

schema = StructType([
    StructField('char', StringType(), nullable=False),
    StructType([
        StructField('num_1', DoubleType, nullable=False),
        StructField('num_2', DoubleType, nullable=True),
        StructField('num_3', DoubleType, nullable=True),
    ])
])
```

Comment: Please check the format of the Dataframe. I have edited my question.